# How to add Fragments to back stack in Android

Tags: android, android-fragments, back-stack

I have created an app having five screens using Sherlock Fragment.

I can jump from one Screen to any other Screen.

But I want to save the last visited fragment name to back-stack,so that from current Fragment i can jump back to the parent(from where i came) Fragment.

I have tried this code,

```
    FragmentManager fragManager = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragTransacion = fragManager.beginTransaction();

    FragmentManager.BackStackEntry backEntry=getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryAt(getActivity().getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount());
    String str=backEntry.getName();
    fragTransacion.addToBackStack(str);
```

But my program gets stops unfortunately and telling me NullPointerException there

How can i achieve this ?

Here is my log-cat,
[logcat](http://pastie.org/8869912)

Comment: please post your logcat

Comment: what is there in line number 44 in  AboutUs.java ?

Answer (score 3):

You can do it like this

```
FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
transaction.replace(R.id.content, fragment);
transaction.addToBackStack("");
transaction.commit();
```

Comment: This helped me so much. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

use `getSupportFragmentManager()` every where instead of `getFragmentManager()`

replace

```
   FragmentManager.BackStackEntry backEntry=getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryAt(getActivity().getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount());
```

with

```
   FragmentManager.BackStackEntry backEntry=getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryAt(getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount());
```

Also you need to perform some transaction before adding to backstack

```
FragmentManager fragManager = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragTransacion = fragManager.beginTransaction();

    FragmentManager.BackStackEntry backEntry=getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryAt(getActivity().getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount());
    String str=backEntry.getName();
fragTransacion.add(R.id.content_frame, detailFrag);
    fragTransacion.addToBackStack(str);

fragTransacion.commit();
```

Also you should probably use a `count -1` getting item at count index might give `ArrayIndexOutOfBounds`.

Comment: here what is use of "fragTransacion.add(R.id.content_frame, detailFrag)" ?

Comment: any transaction the you make. its just an example. first try to resolve other errors i mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

You got `NullPoinerException` because you try to get backEntry when fragment isn't initialazed (after adding fragment need to wait until it is loaded.Also you need to first attach fragment to activity `fragTransacion.replace(R.id.yoursLayout,new YoursFragment);` and than add to backstack
Instead :

```
 FragmentManager.BackStackEntry backEntry=getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryAt(getActivity().getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount());
        String str=backEntry.getName();
fragTransacion.addToBackStack(str);
```

Use this:

```
fragTransacion.addToBackStack(null);
```

Comment: but how can i use "fragTransacion.replace(R.id.yoursLayout,new YoursFragment)" bcz my target fragment is not fix

Comment: just add fragTransacion.addToBackStack(null); after adding your target fragment